# Is HttpContextAccessor Thread Safe?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

There are two normal ways to access the user's HttpContext, via:

- IHttpContextAccessor (and HttpContextAccessor) that are injected for services as so: `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext`
- Or through the controller's property as so: `this.HttpContext`

In my code base, we make use of both cases. For the usage of `HttpContextAccessor`, we have them mostly in common singleton services that are shared for every request (such as logging, session handling, etc). I think this should be thread-safe as `HttpContextAccessor` should know how to handle it, but I see this tweet that throws me off: https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/907248318538903553

So far it looks okay, but is there any confirmation that it is thread-safe?

Comment: HttpContext is not thread safe, but an instance of IHttpContextAccessor is, that's why it exists and it's clearly safe to use as a static singleton, as documented officially https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-7.0#retrieve-the-current-user-in-an-aspnet-core-app Note that using IHttpContextAccessor is still not recommended *"Plan to eventually retrieve IHttpContextAccessor instances from DI instead"*

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing two different concepts. Thread-safety is only tangentially related to HTTP requests as an HTTP request requires the use of a thread. That's pretty much it, though. HttpContext is request-scoped, so within the context of a single request, you will not have bleed-over, assuming you stay on just one thread or all operating threads run within the context of that particular request.

Where things get wonky is when you start firing off threads that run in the background, i.e. outside the request pipeline. In such situations, HttpContext may or may not exist, or it could be different for the background thread than the original thread. That's where the thread-unsafety comes in.

Long and short, whether or not `HttpContext` is thread-safe is the wrong question to ask. Instead, you need to ask what work is being done on a thread in what context. If you're in the request pipeline, then `HttpContext` will effectively be thread-safe, but that would require capturing all threads you fire off, which then pretty much negates the usefulness of using multiple threads. You might as well just do all the work on the original thread. Handling a web request is not the same as something like a desktop or mobile app. In the latter, you need to keep the main or UI thread free, so spinning off threads is a must. The web doesn't work that way; all threads are transient, serving a particular request and then returning to the pool.

Comment: That's what I assume, as every request is a thread and should be self-contained. We don't spin up new threads to handle section of the code (aside using Async, but that's a different thing).

The only concern is when I have two threads using the same common service, and the service tries to access the HttpContext via `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` at the same time for both threads.

Comment: As long as you inject `HttpContextAccessor` in your services - services being singleton or not - you'll be fine.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. HttpContext could be null and will be null if the context is not within the request pipeline.